# why to use getDerivedStateFromProps and shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs

why to use getDerivedStateFromProps and shouldComponentUpdate ? Both serves the same purpose restrict user from re-rendering the component on conditional basis so why React gives two functions for this

Comment: I think you've misread the documentation. getDerivedStateFromProps is an opportunity for you set state based on props having changed. It replaces componentWillReceiveProps. It's not for you to avoid re-rendering, like shouldComponentUpdate is.

Comment: @ClintonChau : if getDerivedStateFromProps is an opportunity for you set state based on props having changed, so it will re-render the component because we are setting state. So same this functionality shouldCompponentUpdate serves as well. In shouldCompponentUpdate we can check the prevProps as well.

Comment: Not sure where the disconnect is, @Abhishek: gDSFP could cause a re-render on the NEXT opportunity, should you return a new state object while sCU will skip the CURRENT render altogether. The semantics of the two are very different. Maybe you need to rephrase or clarify your question.